# Errors were encountered while processing: libsimgearcore2017.3.1:amd64

Tags: apt

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
    comp123@comp123-ThinkCentre-M71e:~$
```

I Tried looking in the package manager but the package was not there.
It Does not let me download,update or upgrade.
Sudo apt-get -f install does not work.
I know it has something to do with flight gear.

when I do  apt-cache policy libsimgearcore2017.3.1

It says

```
libsimgearcore2017.3.1:
  Installed: 1:2017.3.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~16.04.1
  Candidate: 1:2017.3.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:2017.3.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~16.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/flightgear/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Before it says

```
comp123@comp123-ThinkCentre-M71e:~$ sudo apt-get install mono-completeReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mono-complete is already the newest version (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up libsimgearcore2017.3.1:amd64 (1:2017.3.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~16.04.1) ...
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/share/games/flightgear/Timezone': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package libsimgearcore2017.3.1:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libsimgearcore2017.3.1:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What came before the text you pasted? I expect there's a helpful error message there.

Comment: Where you get this package? It seems to be [third-party](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libsimgearcore). What is the output of `apt-cache policy libsimgearcore2017.3.1` (add to the question)?